# Model order reduction method (Getting snapshots from Ansys Fluent)

Tags: user-defined-functions, fluent, ansys

I wanted to derive a reduced-order model of the Evaporator. In order to do that, I wanted to simulate it in the Ansys Fluent software and use the results of the simulation as snapshots for my model order reduction.

I wanted to know, in order to get the snapshot from the software, should I have any knowledge of "UDF" coding in Ansys, or can I get the required and necessary results from the software as inputs for model order reduction easily?